# Why actors with polygons do not filled normally in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

So here is two examples, in both I have two images in table but with different size. The only difference between examples that one uses Texture and other uses polygon.

1. **Texture** x.png is 130x130 and y.png is 75x75

   ```
   Image image1 = new Image(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("y.png"))));
   Image image2 = new Image(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("x.png"))));
   mainTable.setFillParent(true);
   mainTable.row();
   mainTable.add(image1).uniform().fill();
   mainTable.add(image2).uniform();
   mainTable.pack();
   ```

output:

[image: textures]

As you can see first image is filled to second one size, but in base they have different sizes.

---

2. **Polygon**

   ```
   Image image1 = new Image(new PolygonRegionDrawable(new PolygonRegion(getSolidTexture(Color.YELLOW), new float[]{0, 0, 75, 75, 0, 75, 75, 0}, new short[]{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2})));
   Image image2 = new Image(new PolygonRegionDrawable(new PolygonRegion(getSolidTexture(Color.YELLOW), new float[]{0, 0, 130, 130, 0, 130, 130, 0}, new short[]{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2})));
   mainTable.setFillParent(true);
   mainTable.row();
   mainTable.add(image1).uniform().fill();
   mainTable.add(image2).uniform();
   mainTable.pack();
   ```

where

```
    public TextureRegion getSolidTexture(Color color) {
        Pixmap p = new Pixmap(1, 1, RGBA8888);
        p.setColor(color);
        p.fill();
        Texture t = new Texture(p);
        return new TextureRegion(t);
    }
```

ouput:

[image: polygon]

As you can see first image isn't filled to second image size.

Actually why the behavior isn't the same for polygons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I figured out PolygonRegion must be the same size as vertices and only after that it normally scaled.

In my code I just need to scale my vertices array to the same size as my pixmap.

```
    float[] vertices1 = {0, 0, 75, 75, 0, 75, 75, 0};
    vertices1 = GeometryUtils.scale(vertices1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    Image image1 = new Image(new PolygonRegionDrawable(new PolygonRegion(resources.getSolidTexture(Color.YELLOW), vertices1, new short[]{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2})));
    float[] vertices2 = {0, 0, 130, 130, 0, 130, 130, 0};
    vertices2 = GeometryUtils.scale(vertices2, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    Image image2 = new Image(new PolygonRegionDrawable(new PolygonRegion(resources.getSolidTexture(Color.YELLOW), vertices2, new short[]{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2})));
    mainTable.setFillParent(true);
    mainTable.row();
    mainTable.add(image1).uniform().fill();
    mainTable.add(image2).uniform();
    mainTable.pack();
```

At least for me it is very strange that I cannot find that info in Google or internet at all. After despair I found the solution while debugging.